# Loading File "EventLog.js" fails under Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, requirejs

I'm trying to load some modules in the browser with `require.js`. This works fine in Chrome etc. But Firefox fails to load a file called `EventLog.js`.
I tested with a content of EventLog.js like this:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    var Foo = /** @class */ (function () {
        function Foo() {
        }
        return Foo;
    }());
    exports.Foo = Foo;
});
```

Strange - When I change the Filename from `EventLog.js` to `EventLog1.js` it's working. What could be the reason for this? Is `EventLog.js` a reserved Filename?

Comment: could be a cache issue

Comment: Disabled the cache under developer tools. In addition cleared the cache and restarted firefox. Still same failure.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem when working on a web interface that had a file named "eventlog.js". The root cause of my problem was that I am using an ad blocker. There is a filter in the EasyPrivacy list that blocks files named "eventlog.js".

I guess you solved your problem since the question was asked but for anyone still encountering it I recommend checking without your ad blocker. It may not be the root of YOUR problem but it will save you time if it is.

So what are the solutions ?
- easy way: Use another name for your file
- long way: Try to work out a solution with the EasyList team 
- broken way: whitelist the page in your blocker. It will still be broken for your users if they happen to use an ad blocker.